# Magic numbers BIG-LITTLE endian

Tags: protocol

I'm long time really confused about LITTLE/BIG endian encoding. With regard to bitcoin when you check protocol documentation [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Message_structure) it says that btc magic number as send over the wire **0xF9BEB4D9** which has to be as RFC1700 specifies BIG ENDIAN.

However in [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2337/how-was-the-magic-network-id-value-chosen/2355#2355) thread, one answer states that **0xF9BEB4D9** is little endian encoded.

Can soemone explain, please?

Comment: RFC 1700 isn't a law.  Protocols can use little endian if their designers feel like it.  It's not like the Internet police are going to come and arrest them.

Answer (score 2):

Byte sequences have no endianness, numbers do. Satoshi didn't say that clients must send that number, but the byte sequence. Arbitrarily, he chose to use the little-endian byte sequence, corresponding to his number. He didn't disobey RFC1700 because he didn't say that is derived by serializing his number.